# About non-squares in $\mathbb F_p^*$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a problem concerning the prime field $\mathbb F_p^*$ to solve. It is empirically verified that every non-square element, is in $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ different ways a product of  a square by a non-square.

**Example**.- In $\mathbb F_{11}^*$ the squares are $\{1,3,4,5,9\}$ and $2$ (*as well as the other non-square elements,$6,7,8,10$*) is equal to five products as indicated above  $$2=1\cdot2=3\cdot8=4\cdot6=5\cdot7=9\cdot10$$

Prove or disprove this property about the non-squares in $\mathbb F_p^*$.

Comment: The only thing to see here is that the product of two non-squares is a square which is a consequence of the fact that $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is cyclic.

Comment: What you say is also a consequence of the multiplicativity of Legendre symbol. I do not see however an answer to this question. Can you give it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $x \mapsto x^2$ is a homomorphism $\mathbb F_p^\times \to \mathbb F_p^\times$. Its kernel is $\{1,-1\}$ and has order $2$. Its image is a subgroup $Q$ of index $2$. Therefore, $\mathbb F_p^\times = Q \cup aQ$, where $a$ is a nonsquare. The set of nonsquares is exactly $aQ$, which has size $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$. Finally, if $q \in Q$, then $qQ=Q$ and $aQ=aqQ$.

Comment: Academic answer. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a$ be a non-square in $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ (where $q$ is some prime power, it is not necessary to restrict ourselves to $\mathbb{F}_p$).

Then for any other non-square $b \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$ its inverse $b^{-1}$ is also a non-square whence $ab^{-1}$ is a square and is the unique element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that $b \cdot (ab^{-1}) = a$.

So we have shown that for any non-square $b$ there is exactly one square which multiplied with $b$ gives $a$. Now exactly half of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ are squares so there are exactly $\frac{q-1}{2}$ such decompositions.

Side note: The same proof shows that any square can be written in $\frac{q-1}{2}$ ways as a product of two squares or in $\frac{q-1}{2}$ ways as a product of two non-squares.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think however that you have to edit something. For example, what happen when $b$ is precisely the inverse of $a$?. In this case you would have $b\cdot(ab^{-1})=?$.

Comment: When $b$ is the inverse of $a$ we have $bab^{-1} = a^{-1} a b^{-1} = b^{-1} =a$...

Comment: I immediately see your reply before I read it.

Comment: Before I put your answer as being the satisfactory one, explain please the meaning of your "and is the unique element of  $\mathbb F_p^*$ such that $b \cdot (ab^{-1}) = a$". Thank you.

Comment: I have put you an upvote (I'm sure you also consider the answer of lhf as the best). Thanks.

Comment: What I meant to say was $ab^{-1}$ is the unique element solving the equation $bx = a$. And yes, I indeed like lhf's answer better than my own one.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $p>2$. Since $G=\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a cyclic group, given any $g$ such that $\langle g\rangle =G$ we have that the quadratic residues in $G$ are exactly the elements of the form $g^{\text{even}}$ and the non-quadratic residues the elements of the form $g^{\text{odd}}$. It follows that the quadratic residues are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and the product of two quadratic non-residues is a quadratic residue, since $\text{odd}+\text{odd}=\text{even}$.

Comment: Also $\left(\dfrac{ab}{p}\right)=\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)\left(\dfrac{b}{p}\right)$ but I fear this do not answer the question (or it remains to add something to do it). Regards.

Comment: @Piquito: of course we may say that the Legendre symbol is multiplicative *since* $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a cyclic group.